# how to send touch event from one app to another app

Tags: android, twilio, touch-event

I have developed screen casting app. I am making connection using twilio but I want to share touch events from receiver(participant) to sender(host) as a live data. Is there any possible solution to simplify this?

Comment: No idea what you mean but a `MotionEvent` is a class it has properties like x, y etc . you can just convert it to `Json` send it wherever u want. If you want to show tap gesture with the screen sharing you have to enable it from developer Options -> `Show tap` or you'll have to draw it by yourself on the video frame i guess.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ADM I want to send MotionEvent properties(x,y) from one device to another device, like when I touch on phone1 it will show clicked points on phone2's screen. is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Twilio Video for this connection then you can use the [DataTrack API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/using-datatrack-api) to send arbitrary data over your connection.

You can create a `LocalDataTrack` object:

```js
const { LocalDataTrack } = require(`twilio-video`);
const dataTrack = new LocalDataTrack();
```

Connect it to a room, either by sending it as part of the `tracks` option when connecting, or by publishing it to the room after a connection has been made.

```js
const { connect } = require('twilio-video');

const room = await connect('$TOKEN', {
  name: 'my-chat-room',
  tracks: [dataTrack]
});
```

You can send a message down the data track once it is published:

```js
dataTrack.send(message)
```

And you can receive data track messages by subscribing to the track and listening for the `message` event:

```js
participant.on('trackSubscribed', track => {
  console.log(`Participant "${participant.identity}" added ${track.kind} Track ${track.sid}`);
  if (track.kind === 'data') {
    track.on('message', data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
});
```

See [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/using-datatrack-api) for more detail.